# Bend Modifiers not Bending Bottom Face

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have been trying to curve this object. It is supposed to be a rubber keypad and I want to show that it's bendy. I have tried simple deform, surface deform and even cloth modifiers. No matter what I do, the bottom stays straight/flat and the top bows. I want the bottom to bow proportionally. I have merged and checked face orientations. Any ideas? I haven't found any other issues exactly like mine.

https://imgur.com/a/9wfnpPR

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Will do, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

After modeling your keypad, add a simple mesh object that completely contains your rubber keypad object.

It can be a cube, scaled to ensure it is just slightly bigger to envelope the keypad mesh. Make sure you apply the scale after adjusting size, before proceeding.

[image]

Add a *Subdivison Surface* to your box mesh with a low value, like just 2 or 3 subdivisions.

In the *Physics* tab, add a *Cloth* physics type to your box. Turn on *Pressure*, and set a low value like `0.01` or `0.05`. This will prevent the keypad from collapsing on itself. The actual absolute *Pressure* value may vary according to the actual size in Blender units you made your keypad.

[image]

Play your animation to see if the result is satisfactory.

On the rubber keypad mesh, add a *Mesh Deform* modifier, set it to the previously created Box object, and press the *Bind* button.

[image]

If you play the animation now the keypad should deform following the shape of the cloth box. Adjust the cloth parameters to your liking.

[image]

Comment: This worked great,,thank you so much.

Comment: @gab great to hear. If the answer helped you in any way, [upvote it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).